# How to save questions and answers in pairs in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app where the user inputs multiple questions and answers together, and the app later reads these. I'm having trouble saving more than just one value at a time to a file. This is what I have currently:

```
// write text to file
public void WriteBtn(View v) {
    // add-write text into file
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("question.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write(question.getText().toString());
        outputWriter.close();

        //display file saved message
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //n++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and for reading:

```
public void ReadBtn(View v) {
    //reading text from file
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("question.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
            // char to string conversion
            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            s +=readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        //question.setText(s);
        questionArea.setText(s);
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set mode to append also can be done like this
  `openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);`